# How to make a query comparing a field with all items in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a document where the field "questionId" value is different from every item inside the "questionsIdsInThisTurn" array

```js
let questionsIdsInThisTurn = [/*Quentions Ids here*/]

async function getNewQuestion() {
    const ref = firestore.collection('questions')

    const questionData = await ref
      .where(
        "questionId",
        "!=",
        //Every item inside the "questionsIdsInThisTurn" array
      )
      .limit(1)
      .get();

    questionData.forEach(question => {
      questionsIdsInThisTurn.push(question.data().id)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) it give you an example on `not-in` This is called

```
array-contains-any
```

So this should work

```js
let questionsIdsInThisTurn = [1,5,6]

async function getNewQuestion() {
    const ref = firestore.collection('questions')

    const questionData = await ref
      .where(
        "questionId",
        "not-in",
         questionsIdsInThisTurn
      )
      .limit(1)
      .get();

    questionData.forEach(question => {
      questionsIdsInThisTurn.push(question.data().id)
    )
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `not-in` then?

Comment: Yes, sorry i updated my answer. Use not-in